# What's the difference between "if -if -else" and "if-elif-else"

Tags: python, if-statement

[HackerRank: Grading Students](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grading/problem)

when I typed this code:

```
def gradingStudents(grades):
    ls = []
    for grade in grades:
        if grade <38:
            new_grade = grade
        else:
            n = grade //10
            t = grade % 10 
            if t <5 and (5-t)<3:
                new_grade = n * 10 + 5

            if t > 5 and (t - 5) >2:
                new_grade = (n+1) * 10
            else:
                new_grade =grade
        ls.append(new_grade)   
    return ls
```

It's get the wrong answer.But when I changed the second if statement to elif,it's correct.I'm not very clear about what happened:

```
 def gradingStudents(grades):
    ls = []
    for grade in grades:
        if grade <38:
            new_grade = grade
        else:
            n = grade //10
            t = grade % 10 
            if t <5 and (5-t)<3:
                new_grade = n * 10 + 5

            # I use "elif" replace "if"
            elif t > 5 and (t - 5) >2:
                new_grade = (n+1) * 10
            else:
                new_grade =grade
        ls.append(new_grade)   
    return ls
```

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else

Answer (score 4):

Consider the difference:

```
if True:
    print('a')
if True:
    print('b')
else:
    print('c')
```

and

```
if True:
    print('a')
elif True:
    print('b')
else:
    print('c')
```

The first code block will output:

```
a
b
```

While the second will output:

```
a
```

an `if-elif-else` block is *one* conditional. Python will try each `if/elif` in turn until it finds a branch to execute.

An `if-if-else` is two blocks: `if` and `if-else`. They are not dependent on each other, and both blocks might execute.

---

In your specific case I believe it's taking this path:

```
if t <5 and (5-t)<3:        # True! Execute!
    new_grade = n * 10 + 5

if t > 5 and (t - 5) >2:    # False, skip
    new_grade = (n+1) * 10
else:                       # No if was hit in this block -- execute!
    new_grade = grade       # uh oh, we just overwrote our previous result..
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a series of `if` statements. The program will check if each statment is correct.

```
if x == z:
#checks if this statement is true
if x == y:
#also checks if this statement is true
if x == m:
#also checks if this statement is true
```

With `elif` statements however, they will only be checked if the statements above are false.

And example of this is:

```
if x == y:

elif x == m: #this statement will only be checked if the above statement is false

elif x == b #this statement will only be checked if both statements above are false

else: #this will go into effect if all statements above are false.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first form `if-if-if` test all conditions, whereas the second `if-elif-else` tests only as many as needed: if it finds one condition that is True, it stops and doesn't evaluate the rest. In other words: `if-elif-else` is used when the conditions are mutually exclusive.

Below code might help you understand:

```
a = 1
if a == 1:  # Will check this condn
   print ("Correct")
if a == 1:  # Will check this condn
   print ("Correct")
else:      
   print ("No")

if a == 1:  # Will check only this condn
   print ("If-Correct")
elif a == 1:
   print ("Elif")
else:
   print ("Else")
```

Output:

```
Correct
Correct
If-Correct
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Answer (score 0):

if-if-if checks all the conditions and will return all the TRUE results...Where as IF-elif-else is one condition staement and will be executed for one tRUE condition..